# React Typescript - Change default loaded component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

Hello I'm using this library here as a starter kit for my project:  https://github.com/VelinGeorgiev/spfx-react-router/tree/02e829ef432fc1f02e4fdaa7a7da6b54a2fe0b7e (I was using this version, not the newer one.

The problem I'm having is by default it's trying to load the `Home` component which doesn't exist. I want by default the app to route to the `Screen1` component.

Here is what my Webapp.tsx looks like:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { HashRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Screen1 } from './Screen1';
import { Screen2 } from './Screen 2'; 

    export default class Webapp extends React.Component<IWebappProps, {}> {
    
    
      public render(): React.ReactElement<IWebappProps> {
        return (
            <Router>
    
                <ul>
                    <li><Link to="/" >Home</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/screen1" >screen1</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/screen2" >screen2</Link></li>
                </ul>
    
                <Route path="/screen1" render={() => <Screen1/>} />
                <Route path="/screen2" component={screen2} />
    
            </Router>
        );      
    
    }
```

I'm not too sure what page in this library tells the project which component to route to first. Right now when I go on my app the screen is blank until I click on either screen1 or screen2 from the `ul` list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define home route. Like this:

```
<Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
<Route path="/screen1" render={() => <Screen1/>} />
<Route path="/screen2" component={screen2} />
```

If you want to make the default route to /screen1, you can use this:

```
<Route path="/screen1" render={() => <Screen1/>} />
<Route path="/screen2" component={screen2} />
<Route path="/" exact render={() => <Redirect to="/screen1" />} />
```

Hope this will be useful.

Comment: now what if I want to remove home route all together. I want `Screen1` to be essentially my home route.

Comment: Ah! There you go perfect! One last question. So now that my "home" is considered `screen1` if I wanted to change the name of `screen1` to just be `/` so that my home screen is `mywebsite.com` rather than `mywebsite.com/screen1` would this be done here?

Comment: You can simply use this: <Route path="/" exact render={() => <Screen1/>} />. then the screen1 component will be displayed when you go to mywebsite.com.

Comment: please check it solved once it helped you. thank you.

Comment: Yes your solution worked. But what if I wanted to do away with `screen1` so I want `screen1` to actually be my `\` if that makes sense.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you tell me in more detail what you want exactly?

Comment: sorry about that. So right now when I got my my site, it automatically routes to `mysite.com/screen1`. So now yes it's showing the right component, but essentially I would rather my `screen1` be my home. So that when you go to `mysite.com` it shows screen1. Does that make sense.

Comment: I think i replied already to previous comment: <Route path="/" exact render={() => <Screen1/>} />. Does it not work for you?

Comment: Ah yes! my mistake that worked! Sorry last thing. How do I rename `screen1` altogether to be `\`. So right now what you said works. However `mysite.com/screen1` should not exist anymore it should just redirect to the `\` instead. I did this `<Route path="/" render={() => <Screen1/>} />` but when I do that it loads `screen1` and `screen2` on the homepage.

Comment: You have to add exact to / path. `<Route path="/" exact render={() => <Screen1/>} />`, `<Route path="/screen1" exact render={() => <Screen1/>} />`, `<Route path="/screen2" exact component={screen2} />`. Then, path / and /screen1 will render screen1 and /screen2 will render screen2 component.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can change `<App/>` from index.ts to `<screen1/>`
or use history.push("/screen1") from `react-router history` on the startup

Comment: my index.ts is empty it has this in comments `// A file is required to be in the root of the /src directory by the TypeScript compiler`

Comment: that's the part that was giving me trouble in this library I can't find where I change it to screen1

Comment: How index.ts is empty? It is supposed to has -by default- the functionality to render your whole app into root?, add it manually  ReactDOM.render(....)

Comment: no idea why it's empty. I'm new to react. But, if you click on the link I posted in my original post that Github links to the project. So it's empty and I have no idea what they are doing instead.